# Bluetooth signal returns 0

Tags: serial, bluetooth

I have started programming Arduino in the last month. Now I'm working with a bluetooth module. But when I send some data from the Android device to the Arduino, it stays for a very short time and after that  immediately it becomes `0`.

Why does it become `0`? And how can I get rid of that problem?

Here is my code:

```
int x,y;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() 
{
  if(Serial.available()>0)
  {
    x=Serial.parseInt();
    y=Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.print("x:");
    Serial.print(x);
    Serial.print("\n");
    Serial.print("y:");
    Serial.print(y);
    Serial.print("\n");
  }
  else
  {
    ;
  }
}
```

and here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Serial.parseInt()` has a timeout. If something arrives on the serial, or is left over from a previous transmission and hasn't been read yet, `Serial.parseInt()` will start looking for a number to parse. When that fails it times out (and so does the second one immediately after it). When that timeout occurs `parseInt()` just returns 0.

IMHO the Arduino serial parsing routines are very poorly written and should be avoided. I have some tips on how to properly read serial [here](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/).